# What kinds of libraries not needed to be specified in GCC? 

Tags: c, gcc

I was wondering what kinds of libraries used in code are not needed to specify to gcc command? Is /usr/lib/libc.a the only one?

What kinds of libraries are needed to specify to gcc?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4):

You can get an idea of what arguments gcc automatically passes to the linker by using the `-dumpspecs` switch. For example, on my Windows 7 setup with MinGW using:

```
gcc -dumpspecs | less
```

under libgcc section it shows:

```
*libgcc:
%{mthreads:-lmingwthrd} -lmingw32  %{shared-libgcc:-lgcc_s} -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt
```

which suggest those libraries are passed to the ld linker unless I explicitly forbid it with options like `nodefaultlibs` or `nostdlib`. Your gcc dumpspec will look different depending on the host-platform, OS and target it was configured to work with.

**Edit:** To help answer the questions in Tim's comment.

According to the [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Spec-Files.html) the meaning of the spec strings `lib` and `libgcc` are as follows:

```
 lib          Libraries to include on the command line to the linker
 libgcc       Decides which GCC support library to pass to the linker
```

As I understand it, both lib and libgcc are passed to the linker by default. This next part I'm not too sure about, so someone please correct if I'm wrong, if options like `nodefaultlib` get passed in then only the lib spec string will be applied but the libgcc won't.

I just checked the dumpspec for gcc 4.4.x on Ubuntu running under virtual-box and it appears the libc library gets included under the lib spec string.

```
*lib:
%{pthread:-lpthread}    %{shared:-lc}    %{!shared:%{mieee-fp:-lieee} %{profile:-lc_p}%{!profile:-lc}}
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! (1) What differences are between section libgcc and lib? Are the libraries under these two sections all linked by default? (2) Is standard C library by default linked?

Comment: @Tim I updated my answer; hopefully it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! (1) What does "GCC support library" mean? Are most libraries supported by GCC? (2) "if options like nodefaultlib get passed in then only the lib spec string will be applied but the libgcc won't." Do you mean that we can only remove default libraries in "lib" section, but not in "libgcc" section?

Comment: @Tim I believe 'gcc support library' here means the object files and libraries that needs to be linked against to produce a basic runnable executable. Regarding the second question, no gcc actually allows you to modify pretty much anything in the spec file or even supply your own spec file. [This link has more details](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/SpecsFileHOWTO).